# How to chose between the present perfect and the preterite form of a verb?

Tags: present-perfect, past-simple

In the situation in which I want to say to someone on seeing them again after many months that I could not wait to see them again, should I say: "I missed you so much." or "I have missed you so much."?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both are possible, but the perfect is much more likely.

If you use the simple past (*I missed you so much*), you are regarding the time of missing them as finished.

This might mean, for example, that you were thinking back to specific moments when you missed them, rather than the whole extended period of missing them.

But a more obvious interpretation of the simple past would be "but I stopped missing you": that might not be what you want to imply!

Answer (score 1):

Either one of those would work in that situation, where the missing ends at the present moment. If one was talking about someone who got back last month, only the simple past would apply.
 On the other hand, if one were talking about a long history of experiences of missing, then the present perfect might apply if that history extends to the present.